# Why isn't the Kernel receveing my generic netlink messages?

Tags: c, netlink

I'm trying to send nested attributes from user space to kernel using generic netlink, the function `nl_send_auto()` returns 52 (which was supposed to be the numbers of bytes sent to kernel) but the kernel isn't receiving the messages. Is there some problem with my approach? Here is the code that I wrote on user space:

```
int err = -1;
struct nl_msg *msg;
struct nlattr *attr;
struct nl_sock *sock;
int family;
int send = 0;

if ((sock = nl_socket_alloc()) == NULL)
    return err;

if ((err = genl_connect(sock)))
    return err;

if ((family = genl_ctrl_resolve(sock, FAMILY)) < 0)
    return family;

if ((msg = nlmsg_alloc()) == NULL)
    return err;

if ((genlmsg_put(msg, NL_AUTO_PORT, NL_AUTO_SEQ, FAMILY, 0, 
    NLM_F_REQUEST, CREATE_STATE, 1)) == NULL)
    return err;

if (!(attr = nla_nest_start(msg, KLUA_NL_STATE))){
    nla_nest_cancel(msg, attr);
    return err;
}

if ((ret = nla_put_string(msg, STATE_NAME, cmd->name)) ||
    (ret = nla_put_u32(msg, MAX_ALLOC, cmd->maxalloc)) ||
    (ret = nla_put_u32(msg, CURR_ALLOC, cmd->curralloc))
    )
    return err;

nla_nest_end(msg, attr);

if ((send = nl_send_auto(ctrl->sock, msg)) < 0)
    return send;

printf("All done sended %d bytes\n", send);

nlmsg_free(msg);
```

This code prints 52, which is the bytes sent to kernel;

The FAMILY macro is defined as (both in kernel and user space):

```
#define FAMILY "family"
```

My netlink attributes are (both for kernel and user space):

```
enum {
    KLUA_NL_STATE,
    STATE_NAME,
    MAX_ALLOC,
    CURR_ALLOC,
    ATTR_COUNT,
#define ATTR_MAX (ATTR_COUNT - 1)
};
```

My enum for operation is:

```
enum {
    CREATE_STATE = 16,
};
```

And my kernel code is:

```
struct nla_policy lunatik_policy[ATTR_MAX] = {
    [KLUA_NL_STATE] = { .type = NLA_NESTED },
};

static int klua_create_state(struct sk_buff *buff, struct genl_info *info);

static const struct genl_ops l_ops[] = {
    {
        .cmd    = CREATE_STATE,
        .doit   = klua_create_state,
#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE < KERNEL_VERSION(5,2,0)
        /*Before kernel 5.2.0, each operation has its own policy*/
        .policy = lunatik_policy
#endif
    },
};

#define KLUA_NL_STATE_ATTRS_COUNT 3

struct genl_family lunatik_family = {
    .name    = FAMILY,
    .version = 1,
    .maxattr = ATTR_MAX,
    .netnsok = true,
    .policy  = lunatik_policy,
    .module  = THIS_MODULE,
    .ops     = l_ops,
    .n_ops   = ARRAY_SIZE(l_ops),
};

static int klua_create_state(struct sk_buff *buff, struct genl_info *info)
{
    pr_info("I received the message\n");
    return 0;
}
```

This code doesn't print anything on dmesg, and I would like to know why.

Answer (score 1):

## You actual problems

During Linux 5.2 refactors, the semantics of the `NLA_F_NESTED` flag changed somewhat. It appears you now need to always include it when you call `nla_nest_start()`:

```
if (!(attr = nla_nest_start(msg, KLUA_NL_STATE))){
    ...
}
```

Should be

```
if (!(attr = nla_nest_start(msg, NLA_F_NESTED | KLUA_NL_STATE))){
    ...
}
```

Yes, I'm well aware the libnl library should obviously do this for you, and will perhaps do so in the future, but unfortunately this is where we are now.

Also:

```
enum {
    KLUA_NL_STATE,
    ...
};
```

Attribute zero is always reserved. You need to change that into

```
enum {
    KLUA_NL_STATE = 1,
    ...
};
```

Just FYI: operation zero is also reserved, so it's fortunate that you chose 16. But do keep it in mind in the future.

## Syntactic issues

These are probably just copy-paste errors, but I'm including them anyway for the benefit on other people landing in this page looking for examples.

```
if ((genlmsg_put(msg, NL_AUTO_PORT, NL_AUTO_SEQ, FAMILY, 0, 
    NLM_F_REQUEST, CREATE_STATE, 1)) == NULL)
    return err;
```

Should be

```
if ((genlmsg_put(msg, NL_AUTO_PORT, NL_AUTO_SEQ, family, 0, 
    NLM_F_REQUEST, CREATE_STATE, 1)) == NULL)
    return err;
```

Also:

```
if ((ret = nla_put_string(msg, STATE_NAME, cmd->name)) ||
    (ret = nla_put_u32(msg, MAX_ALLOC, cmd->maxalloc)) ||
    (ret = nla_put_u32(msg, CURR_ALLOC, cmd->curralloc))
    )
    return err;
```

Should be

```
if ((err = nla_put_string(msg, STATE_NAME, cmd->name)) ||
    (err = nla_put_u32(msg, MAX_ALLOC, cmd->maxalloc)) ||
    (err = nla_put_u32(msg, CURR_ALLOC, cmd->curralloc))
    )
    return err;
```

Also:

```
if ((send = nl_send_auto(ctrl->sock, msg)) < 0)
    return send;
```

Should be

```
if ((send = nl_send_auto(sock, msg)) < 0)
    return send;
```